# Clicking on search bar causes text field to become overly large

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar

I created a custom search bar called `LibrarySearchBar`. When I click on my search bar, the text field becomes overly large. When I click "cancel", the text field stays overly large. How do I fix this?

Also, in debugger, it states, "search field background image only respected for UIControlStateNormal and UIControlStateDisabled. state = 4 is interpreted as UIControlStateDisabled."

**1) Clicks on search bar 2) Clicks "Cancel"**

[image]
[image]

**Code:**

```
class LibrarySearchBar: UISearchBar {
    init(frame: CGRect, font: UIFont, textColor: UIColor, placeholder: String, placeholderColor: UIColor) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.frame = frame
        self.setSearchFieldBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "SearchFieldBackground"), for: UIControlState.normal)
        self.setSearchFieldBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "SearchFieldBackgroundSelected"), for: UIControlState.selected)
        self.backgroundImage = UIImage(named: "SearchBarBackground")
    }
}
```

Comment: Pic of search bar when view controller first loads: https://postimg.org/image/5qghghsi3/. I couldn't add it to my answer due to a stackoverflow glitch

Comment: set your searchbar to normal state.

Comment: @SourLeangChhean what do you mean set the searchbar to a normal state? When the search bar first loads on the screen, it is in a normal state